# Python 3.4.2 | Loop input until set amount

Tags: python

Learning the basics of python and I am running across a problem. I'm sure it is a simple fix. I'm trying to get my program to get 20 different inputs before calculating the min, max, etc.

```
def main():
    number = valueInput()
    display(number)

def valueInput():
    print("Please enter 20 random numbers")
    values = []
    for i in range(20):
        value1 =(int(input("Enter a random number " + str(i + 1) + ": ")))
        values.append(value1)
        return values

def display(number):
    print("The lowest number is:", min(number))
    print("The highest number is:", max(number))
    print("The sum of the numbers is:", sum(number))
    print("The average number is:", sum(number)/len(number))

main()
```

I can get it to work by repeating this line:

```
value1 =(int(input("Enter a random number " + str(i + 1) + ": ")))
```

to the 20th number but there must be a way that makes it shorter and cleaner. Again I am a beginner so any explanation would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do to fix your program is remove four spaces:

```
def valueInput():
    print("Please enter 20 random numbers")
    values = []
    for i in range(20):
        value1 =(int(input("Enter a random number " + str(i + 1) + ": ")))
        values.append(value1)
    return values
```

The last line in the block above has been unindented by one level. Instead of returning after the first time through the loop, it lets the loop complete, and then returns the resulting `list`.

Comment: I feel only slightly dumb. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Also you can change your:

```
values = []
for i in range(20):
    value1 =(int(input("Enter a random number " + str(i + 1) + ": ")))
    values.append(value1)
    return values
```

part with:

```
values = [int(input("Enter a random number " + str(x + 1) + ": ")) for x in list(range(20))]
return values
```

You can check out [build in functions](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/functional.html)